# Read NFC Type B tag and send ID to Android app using Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, rfid

One of my clients needs to scan NFC tags in a bus to recieve their IDs in a Android app.

I'm new to RFID/NFC even if I've read many articles about it, so my question is the following: **what should I use to read an NFC tag and send its ID to an Android App (I have a developper) through a Blutooth connexion.**

Important detail: the tags are ISO 14443B (NFC Type B) wich is very uncommon comaring to Type A, I managed to read Type A tags using an Arduino and a P532 board but the library given with it doesn't support Type B and I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You just need to read the ISO14443 Type B tag UUID and report it over Bluetooth to an Android device?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I want! :D